Why am I not able to select an option in a dropdown with Puppeteer in Javascript?
In the code below I am attempting to use puppeteer to automatically open a list of all of Caeleb Dressel's times on USA Swimming. Because he doesn't have any times in 2025, I have to change the selected option in the first dropdown to the one with value="-1". I use page.select, but for some reason it doesn't work, but everything above the await page.waitForSelector("#competitionYearId"); works perfectly fine. I have tried many other methods, but none of them work, and I'm pretty sure page.select should work perfectly fine. How can I fix this?
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://data.usaswimming.org/datahub/usas/individualsearch");

    await page.waitForSelector("#firstOrPreferredName", { visible: true });
    await page.type("#firstOrPreferredName", "Caeleb");
    await page.type("#lastName", "Dressel");
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

    await page.waitForSelector("._ActionButton_8nq2x_59");
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("._ActionButton_8nq2x_59._ActionIntraPage_8nq2x_159");
        if (buttons[0]) {
            buttons[0].click();
        }
    });
    await page.waitForSelector("#competitionYearId");
    await page.select("#competitionYearId", "-1");
})();

Here's the json I want to pull after navigating to the right page:
{
    "Event Name (Ex: 50 FR SCY)": {
        "Meet Name (Ex: 2018 NCAA DI - Men)": {
            "Time": "17.63",
            "Age": "21",
            "Points": "1138",
            "LSC": "FL",
            "Team": "Unattached",
            "Date": "03/22/18"
        }
    }
}


I'm trying to extract the table of events, times, age, points. etc. shown after you click the dropdown and click the -- option. So maybe the json would look something like this:

